# How to change hover behavior in g.raphaelJS?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am new to raphael and am using the same code as the one shown (specifically the "Symbols, axis, and hover effect" one):

http://g.raphaeljs.com/linechart.html

Image here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0U3N.jpg

What I want to be able to do is on hover on any part of the chart and have a red line that goes from top to bottom of the chart wherever my mouse cursor is. (even if it is not on a specific data point I used, and have a box that says the number it that is on the x axis (even if it is not a data point I used in my graph (i.e. 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4)). How do I accomplish this? Any help would be appreciated.